# cf push does not consider .cfignore

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, devops-services

I am trying to push a node project to Bluemix, and I wanted the cf to ignore the node_modules in my project, so I have this below line in my .cfignore file (at the root of the application)

node_modules/

When I issue the cf push --random-route command, it says that it is loading 48M, 284 files. I think 48M is 48MB of files, so I think the cf push is not considering the .cfignore file. The upload takes lot of time.

*Uploading 48M, 284 files
19.4M uploaded....*

Comment: Can you check Bluemix logs simultaneously?

Comment: Yes did that, I only see this in logs

Updated app with guid c14e5f4d-025a-4646-a24c-5ad7d7dd0593 ({"name"=>"mycgappname", "command"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN", "memory"=>256, "environment_json"=>"PRIVATE DATA HIDDEN"})

Comment: Just for a test, try deleting node_modules, and push again. If it still says 48M, it's not node_modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a file encoding issue. Try deleting the file and downloading this one directly. (File-> Save)

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM-Bluemix/get-started-node/master/.cfignore

Comment: still same, my cf version is cf version 6.23.0+c7866be-2016-12-22, will update cli and will give it a try again

Comment: I think encoding is the issue, when I opened the downloaded .cfignore in notepad, it was still showing ANSI, changed it to UTF-8 and saved it, working now. Thanks Ram.